# In a lighter conditions

Tags: meaning

Which sentence would be grammatically better? Should I use “heavier” without anything or use with “ in a condition” to make it both formal or grammatical?

> We usually wake up  a kilo lighter in the morning.

> We usually wake up in a kilo lighter condition in the morning.

Comment: @Laurel, the first one makes sense, after a fashion: it means (and should say) "We usually wake up a kilo lighter **than when we went to bed.**" FS, the first one is okay if you change it to be comparative *to some other state* (as I did). The second is not correct at all.

Comment: Why is the second one is wrong?

Comment: @randomhead Question was edited since I wrote that...

Comment: Is it really true? A whole kilo?

Comment: I mean is it grammatically wrong or unnecessary?

Comment: @Michael Harvey it depends how many times to get up in the night to pee :-). A true example of the same construction would be "We wake up a centimetre taller than when we went to bed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we use **state** and **condition** in a comparison, we don't tend to quantify the difference.

> He was **in a richer state** when he came back from Saudi ... -*OK*
> He was **in a somewhat richer state** ... -*OK*
> He was **in a 50% richer state** ... -*just about OK*
> He was **in a $10,000 richer state** ... -*not OK*

The last sentence is not grammatically wrong, but people would be very unlikely to say it.

All of the above would be simpler and clearer without "in a .... state", but if you want to quantify the difference, without is the only viable option:

> He was **$10,000 richer** when he came back from Saudi -*OK*